# Javascript. Hover an image moving it to the right revealing image.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok. So I am making a website for my schools rugby team. Right now the logo on top just says "Rugby," It is a .png image. I want to make it so that when you hover over "rugby" it shifts to the right revealing "school name" next to it.

When the cursor is on the logo i want it to read "school name rugby." and when the cursor moves again it covers back up "school name" and just reads "rugby" 
I wanna do this using images not text. Thanks so much! any response is appreciated!

Comment: I need the whole thing to be clickable as well because i'm using it as the home button. I would prefer if this was done animated so it slowly shifts. Not all at once.

Comment: Please give us a https://jsfiddle.net/ with your existing code.

Comment: It will be helpful to tell us what have you tried. Refer to [here for how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: the existing code I have is just css and html. I don't know where to start

Comment: I would assume you just overlay the two images and then on hover it would shift to the side. I just cant find how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for JavaScript or jQuery. You basically just need two images in the same container. Make sure the one that is on top has a higher `z-index`. You need to then set a `hover` state on the containing element while selecting the covering image (I did the `a` tag since you said it needs to be clickable. Then you just move one to the right using a `margin-left` property that is the same as the width of the image. To make it slide, just use a `transition property`. Something like this:

```css
div:hover a:first-child {
      margin-left: 475px;
    }

    a:first-child {
      z-index: 1;
      transition: 1s;
    }

    a {
      position: absolute;
      left: 10;
      top: 10;
    }
```

```html
<div>
       <a href="#">
        <img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png">
       </a>
       <a href="#">
        <img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png">
       </a>
   </div>
```

Here's a jsfiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/salexzee/c0y1za2t/

Comment: I also positioned them absolutely so that they can be set to the exact same position. It's also useful if they're the same size. But if they're different, obviously the covering image needs to be larger and you'll have to figure out the positioning measurements.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is 100% what i was looking for!